# large space at the bottom of Android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

i have an android interface composed of image , textview , `fragment` and another layout with button like the photo bellow , so after adding my shapes , in the IDE android studio it likes normally and organized but in my phone every things changed [image: image in the IDE]

[image: the screen of my app in my phone]

**My xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cricleshape"
        android:layout_width="191dp"
        android:layout_height="191dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle">
        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoprof"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="152dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar_profile_png_picture"
            android:translationX="2dp"
            android:translationY="2dp"
            app:civ_border_width="4dp"
            app:civ_shadow_radius="10dp"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/broderprofile">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/anaheim"
                android:text="Level :"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numlevel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:text="NumLevel"
                android:textColor="#FFFEFE" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameUser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name User"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="323dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bordershape">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailuser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Emai@email.com"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:translationX="12dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="282dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_posts" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="323dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bordershape">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/likepost"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="171dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#B0371C61"
            app:cornerRadius="28dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/like"
            app:iconGravity="top"
            app:iconSize="27dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/white"
            app:startIconTint="@color/white"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/likepostt"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#B0371C61"
            app:cornerRadius="28dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/like"
            app:iconGravity="top"
            app:iconSize="27dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/white"
            app:startIconTint="@color/white"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/likepostr"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="113dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#B0371C61"
            app:cornerRadius="28dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/like"
            app:iconGravity="top"
            app:iconSize="27dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/white"
            app:startIconTint="@color/white"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are setting your elements's height static like below and it's never good:

```
android:layout_height="191dp"
```

It can fit in the IDE copy of a phone but not your real device, because your phone's height and IDE's phone height not equal. Probably your real phone has bigger height, so it will be seen like large space.

You can fix it if your last element covers to the bottom of parent, you can achieve like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="323dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bordershape">
```